# How to make sure that repositories added to Linux Mint are safe and secure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, linux-mint, repository

I’m using the latest version of Linux mint which based on Ubuntu, I have installed many programs by adding a new repository to the list of checked repositories. Now I’m worried of how safe these repositories that I have added previously actually are.

- Is there any program to check that repository that I have used in the past are safe and trusted?
- Is there any antivirus application that check my system the packages I’m using repositories etc… are safe?
- I just don’t want to install new version of Linux because of that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple matter of which repositories you trust. If you use official repositories, the checksums of their packages are checked against checksums stored on official servers so as long as the hash algorithm is secure, you can be sure that the packages you obtained from mirrors are the ones that the official vendor published. But it's still the question if you trust official repositories.

If you expect any stuff you have installed in the past to not be trustworthy, you must consider your complete system flawed and should attempt any anti-virus or whatever checks from at least a live system.

Summing it up: If you are worried, completely reinstall your system and stick to repositories you trust. Keep in mind that there is malware nowadays which can also infect hardware and thus survive a reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

For an antivirus, I'd recommend clamav.

Then it is a simple matter to

```
apt download pkgname && clamav pkgname-ver.sion.number.deb

apt deb pkgname-ver.sion.number.deb
```

For better security, I can offer no more advice than to

```
apt source pkgname && cd pkgname-ver.sion.number-src
```

and then audit the code yourself. Once you are satisfied that the code contains few to no backdoors, you can

```
apt build-dep pkgname && apt build pkgname && apt deb pkgname*.deb
```

For more proprietary packages (spotify and chrome to name a couple) you cannot obtain source code, so you must use the clamav method.

You cannot check an entire repository. You can only check each package individually.

For maximum security, however, you must remove these "Extra repos" and stick with what was provided by the distribution.